# Magic Earth Navigation POI import

Tags: navigation

Custom POIs. I have made a POI in a number of formats:  .rupi,  .gpx,  .asc, .csv, .ov2, .txt,  containing some 250 handicap parking spaces I Denmark. How do I import custom POI with corresponding icon into Magic Earth Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to install "[RupiManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.rupimanager.rupimanager)".
Then put your poi.txt in "Import" folder and export it as KML by the app. 
In the next step you have to open your poi.kml in "export" folder with magic earth.